# Mutual independence in probability

Tags: probability

Let $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $i = 1,2,3$.

Prove that $A=\{X_1=X_2\},  B=\{ X_1=X_3\}, C=\{X_2=X_3\}$ are not MUTUALLY INDEPENDENT. So I know I have to work out $P(A\cap{B}\cap{C})$ and show it's not equal to $P(A)P(B)P(C)$ but I don't know how to go about it since one variable is in terms of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Nitpicking: you should write "$A = \{X_1 = X_2\}$" instead of "$A = X_1 = X_2$."

---

Do you know how to compute $P(A) = P(X_1 = X_2)$?

> $P(A) = P(X_1 = X_2) = P(X_1=1, X_2=1) + P(X_1=-1, X_2 = -1) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$.

Computing $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ can be done similarly. Then you can compute $P(A) P(B) P(C)$.

---

Can you give a simple description (in terms of $X_1, X_2, X_3$) of the event $A \cap B \cap C$?

> $A \cap B \cap C = \{X_1 = X_2 = X_3\}$

Then can you compute the probability of $A \cap B \cap C$?

> $P(X_1=X_2=X_3) = P(X_1=1, X_2=1, X_3=1) + P(X_1=-1, X_2=-1, X_3=-1) = \cdots$

Comment: spotted my mistake, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assume $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are mutually independent.

Let $A$ be the event when $X_1=X_2$, $B$ be the event when $X_1=X_3$, and $C$ be the event when $X_2=X_3$. That is, 
$$
A = \{X_1=X_2\}, \qquad 
B = \{ X_1=X_3\}, \qquad 
C = \{X_2=X_3 \}. 
$$
Note that $A$ has the following outcomes: when $X_1=1$ and $X_2=1$, and when $X_1=-1$ and $X_2=-1$. Events $B$ and $C$ have two similar outcomes.

Since the outcomes for $A$ (when $X_1=1$ and $X_2=1$, and when $X_1=-1$ and $X_2=-1$) cannot occur simultaneously, we have
\begin{align*}
P(A) &= P(X_1=1 \mbox{ and }X_2=1) + P(X_1=-1 \mbox{ and }X_2=-1)  \\
&\qquad -P(X_1=1 \mbox{ and }X_2=1 \mbox{ and }X_1=-1 \mbox{ and }X_2=-1) \\
&= P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1) + P(X_1=-1)P(X_2=-1) -0 \\ 
&=  \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}, 
\end{align*}
where the second equality holds since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Similarly, $P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{2}$.

So 
\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B\cap C) &= P(X_1=1 \mbox{ and } X_2=1 \mbox{ and } X_3=1) 
  \\ 
&\qquad + P(X_1=-1 \mbox{ and } X_2=-1 \mbox{ and } X_3=-1) \\ 
&= P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)P(X_3=1)   \\
&\qquad + P(X_1=-1)P(X_2=-1)P(X_3=-1) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} \\
&= \require{enclose} \enclose{circle}{~~\frac{1}{4}~~}.  
\end{align*}

On the other hand, $P(A)P(B)P(C)=\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}{~\frac{1}{8}~}$.

Thus the events $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not mutually independent.